# DocumentDB error on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Some weird problem occurred when i tried to test my code on azure cloud service "worker role" project. The code worked fine on "Web API" and "Console application" projects.

```
    var databaseDefinition = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Database { Id = DatabaseName };
    _dbClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey);
    var result = await _dbClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseDefinition);
    var collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection { Id = CollectionId };
    
    try
    {
       
       var result = await_dbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(_dbLink.CollectionsLink, collectionDefinition);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       throw e;
    }
```

But whenever i try to run worker role project and initialize my DocumentDB repo, the following error shows up:

*"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
colls
dbs/MyDatabase/colls/MyCollection"*

Exactly the same code runs perfect on Console Application and Web API.
I'm using Azure CosmosDB with [DocumentDB SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your `EndpointUrl` look like (you can replace the identifiable bits before posting)?

Comment: Https://cosmosdbaccount.documents.azure.com:443/

Comment: Is `AuthorizationKey` being read correctly? How are you passing it in? You could log it in the exception.

Comment: AuthorizationKey is being read _dbClient stage where it successfully retrieves the information about database resource. But when trying to CreateOrRetrieve collection it gaves me the exception.